# Is there an email server that can do a REST POST to my end point when an email is received?

Tags: parsing, email, post, mail-server, inbound

I have an application that has a requirement to attach links to emails to client records in the application.

I need an email server that - in addition to behaving like any email server, do a REST POST to my application end point notifying my application about a new email and needs to provide atleast the ID of the email (the ID with which I can open a pop-up browser in my application and view that email) and subject on the email.

I have evaluated a number of inbound parsing solutions but most either don't give me control to pass authentication information or do a POST of type JSON, and not a basic FORM POST.
I have evaluated the following:

1. http://sendgrid.com
2. http://www.email2db.com
3. http://mailparser.io/
4. http://mandrill.com/

Answer (score 0):

- Any mail server, atleast popular MTAs like postfix, sendmail allow you to pipe the email through stdin to a program.
- Once you have the mail content in a program, you can do any magic. ( We have a requirement of parsing every incoming mail, updating the database and leaving a copy of mail in mailbox for reference and we do it through a perl script )